# How to spawn item/block/entity at player death point?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I am working on a Minecraft "Mini-"Game and want a command that makes an entity (like a zombie) spawn at the death point of a player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up an objective (I'm calling it `hasDied` here), and using the `deathCount` criterion to make the objective update when someone dies.

```
/scoreboard objectives add hasDied deathCount
```

You can then use the execute command to summon a zombie for all players that died:

`/execute if entity @a[score_hasDied_min=1] run summon Zombie ~ ~ ~`

also you should reset the values afterwards (with a chain command block):

`/scoreboard players reset @a[score_hasDied_min=1] hasDied`

Comment: 1. I'll test it out! Wich username(please Minecraft username) is the one for the credits?                                                 2. Why does this wepside say: "Please avoide 'thanks' ?"

Comment: My username is Z1proW, but you don't have to credit me. And for your question (2.): https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23549/why-do-we-need-to-avoid-to-thank-somebody

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong, the summon command will fail because if the score has gone up, the player has died and, subsequentially, no longer has a position in the world until the player itself hits the "Revive" button. I think the second command will work, reseting the player's score before even summoning the zombie. I remember answering a similar question sometime ago but I can't find it.

Comment: @Z1proW I don't understand what the people said there (bc I am from Germany )

Comment: @McBlock basically you should avoid a comment answering just "thanks" without any additional content, because you could just accept or upvote the answer.